# ошибка в replace

Tags: python, replace

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(a[0])
print(a[-1])
print(a.replace(8, 99))
print(a.add(47))
print(a.add(50, 5))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
print(a.replace(8, 99))
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Такого метода у списка нет. Не факт что когда-нибудь будет. Если очень нужно, можно использовать такой вариант: `a[a.index(8)] = 99`, правда это заменит только первый элемент с таким значением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s.append(x)
s.clear()
s.copy()
s.extend(t) or s += t
s.insert(i, x)
s.pop() or s.pop(i)
s.remove(x)
s.reverse()
```

Вероятно этот метод еще не написан.

Чтобы поменять восьмой элемент на 99 достаточно в вашем списке a[9]=99